# Rails separate DB migration not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-migrations

I am trying to run a migration to a separate DB in Rails, using `establish_connection`. I have something like this in the migration file:

```
def change
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection("user_#{Rails.env}")
  ActiveRecord::Base.initialize_schema_migrations_table

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "email",  
end
```

In the yml I have this config:

```
user_development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: MyApp_user_development
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  username: xxx
  password: xxx
```

Also I have defined the User Model like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection "user_#{Rails.env}"
  [...]
end
```

Now, the DB exists but when running `rake db:migrate` I get this error:

```
==  CreateUserOnSeparateDb: migrating =========================================
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

connection is closed
```

Does any of you have any idea what is going on?

I have also tried to move the `establish_connection` call into a `connection` method in the migration file. In this case the table is created on migrate but then I get the same error (so somehow failing on other migrations) and by the way it does not create the schema_migrations table...

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved above issue by following below steps.

```
class AddCustomTbl < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def connection
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(Rails.env).connection
  end

  def up
    # Connection with user_#{Rails.env}
    oldEnv = Rails.env
    Rails.env = "user_#{Rails.env}"
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(Rails.env)
    create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
      t.string   "email"
    end
    # Connection with Rails.env
    Rails.env = oldEnv
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env]
  end

  def down
    # Connection with user_#{Rails.env}
    oldEnv = Rails.env
    Rails.env = "user_#{Rails.env}"
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(Rails.env).connection
    drop_table :users
    # Connection with Rails.env
    Rails.env = oldEnv
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env]
  end
end
```